# ... does not implement admission.Validator

Tags: go

I am getting this error:

```
cd hack/tools && go build -tags=tools -o /home/guettli/foo/cluster-api-provider-bar/hack/tools/bin/clusterctl sigs.k8s.io/cluster-api/cmd/clusterctl
# sigs.k8s.io/cluster-api/api/v1beta1
vendor/sigs.k8s.io/cluster-api/api/v1beta1/machine_webhook.go:45:27: cannot use &Machine{} (value of type *Machine) as admission.Validator value in variable declaration: *Machine does not implement admission.Validator (wrong type for method ValidateCreate)
                have ValidateCreate() error
                want ValidateCreate() (admission.Warnings, error)
```

Does someone has a hint how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a breaking change in v0.15.

Downgrading to 0.14.5 helped:

```
❯ go get sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.14.5
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work for me :)